# Linq with alias

Tags: c#, linq, alias

I have the following line in c#:

```
var name = (from x in db.authors
                    where fullName == "Jean Paul Olvera"
                    orderby x.surname
                    select new { x.id_author, fullName= String.Concat(x.name," ", x.surname) });
```

my problem is I want to use the alias in my where clause, but I can't, 'fullName' appears as not declared.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `let` to create intermediate values:

```
var name = (from x in db.authors
            let fullName = x.name + " " + x.surname
            where fullName == "Jean Paul Olvera"
            orderby x.surname
            select new { x.id_author, fullName });
```

Comment: could define a alias for `fullname`?

Comment: @combo_ci I don't understand your question. That's exactly what this code does.

Answer (score 11):

You need to put that part of the projection earlier, which is easy with a [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
var name = from x in db.authors
           let fullName = x.name + " " + x.surname
           where fullName == "Jean Paul Olvera"
           orderby x.surname
           select new { x.id_author, fullName };
```

Note that `x.name + " " + x.surname` will be compiled to the same code as `String.Concat(x.name, " ", x.surname)`, but is more readable to most people. Also note that as you're not doing anything outside the `()` parentheses, there's no need for them.

I would *hope* that any good SQL LINQ provider should turn this query into a sensible and efficient SQL query, but you should validate this yourself. On the other hand, I would *generally* suggest preferring querying over individual fields, e.g.

```
where x.name == "Jean Paul" && x.surname == "Olvera"
```

Answer (score 7):

You haven't created it yet.

That being said, since you know the name in advance, you should be able to perform the query on the parts:

```
var name = from x in db.authors
                where name == "Jean Paul" && surname == "Olvera"
                orderby x.surname
                select new { x.id_author, fullName= String.Concat(x.name," ", x.surname) };
```

Otherwise, you can use `let` to do this:

```
var name = from x in db.authors
           let fullName = String.Concat(x.name," ", x.surname)
           where fullName == "Jean Paul Olvera"
           orderby x.surname
           select new { x.id_author, fullName=fullName ) };
```

Answer (score 6):

It's easier in the method syntax, as you aren't constrained to the order of the operations:

```
var query = authors.OrderBy(x => x.surname)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.id_author,
        fullName = String.Concat(x.name, " ", x.surname)
    })
    .Where(x => x.fullName == "Jean Paul Olvera");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
linq1DataContext ll = new linq1DataContext();
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {

                var q = from m in ll.personals                            



                        let کد= m.id
                        let نام = m.name

                        select new { 
                                     کد,
                                     نام,
                        };
                dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
            }
```

Comment: could define a alias such as `نام و نام خانوادگی`?

Answer (score 2):

use the `let` clause:

```
var name = (from x in db.authors
                let fullName = String.Concat(x.name," ", x.surname)
                where fullname = "Jean Paul Olvera"
                orderby x.surname
                select new { x.id_author, fullName });
```